# Geometric Computations for Triangle

Tags: java

So I made a triangle program where a user inputs 3 sides. After receiving the three values, your program should provide answers for each of the following questions:

1. Is it really a triangle? If one side is longer than the sum of the other two sides, then it is not.
2. Is it a right triangle? That is, does it satisfy the Pythagorean theorem?
3. Is it an equilateral triangle? That is, are all three sides the same?
4. Is it an isosceles triangle? That is, are two sides the same? (If your program has already determined that the triangle is equilateral, then it should NOT state that it is isosceles.)
5. What is the area of the triangle?
6. What is the perimeter of the triangle?

The only thing that I'm stuck on is the part where it says if your program has already determined that the triangle is equilateral, then it should not state that it is isosceles. So I need a little help to figure out how to fix that if I input something like 2,2,2.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Triangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Triangle Program");
    System.out.println();
    double side1, side2, side3;
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of side 1:");
    side1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of side 2:");
    side2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of side 3:");
    side3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("My analysis of this triangle is");
    System.out.println();

    if((side1 > side2+side3) || (side2 > side1+side3) || (side3 > side1+side2))
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a triangle");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is a triangle");
    }
    if((side1*side1 == (side3*side3)+(side2*side2)) || (side2*side2 == (side3*side3)+(side1*side1)) || (side3*side3 == (side1*side1)+(side2*side2)))
    {
        System.out.println("This is a right triangle");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is not a right triangle");
    }
    if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3))
    {
        System.out.println("This is an equilateral triangle");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is not an equilateral triangle");
    }
    if((side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side3 == side1))
    {
        System.out.println("This is an isosceles triangle");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This is not an isosceles triangle");
    }

    double p = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2.0;
    double area = Math.sqrt(p * (p - side1) * (p - side2) * (p - side3));
    double perimeter = side1 + side2 + side3;
    System.out.printf("The area of the triangle is " + "%.3f",area);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The perimeter of the triangle is " + perimeter);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, you can always just add the check for equilateral-ness to the check for isosceles-ness (negated, of course): `((side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side3 == side1)) && !((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3))`. Although, I would dispute that an equilateral triangle is not isosceles.

Comment: Wow, never even thought of that....thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the check for equilateral-ness to the check for isosceles-ness (negated, of course):

```
((side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side3 == side1))
  && !((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3))
```

Although, I would dispute that an equilateral triangle is not isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of complex boolean expressions. I think you should create a boolean variable first, to store whether the triangle is equilateral:

```
boolean isEquilateral = false;
```

And when your test of equilateral triangle succeeds, set it to true.

```
if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3))
{
    System.out.println("This is an equilateral triangle");
    isEquilateral = true;
}
```

Before you check for isosceles-ness, check the boolean variable:

```
if(!isEquilateral && (side1 == side2) || (side2 == side3) || (side3 == side1))
{
    System.out.println("This is an isosceles triangle");
}
```